# Bootstrap drop down event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to select the value with event of li element?

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" value="1" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle">
      Select  <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropDownId">
    </ul>
  </div>
```

i fill it dynamically

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.stuff.length; i++){

  $("#dropDownId").append("<li><a data-value='"+i+"'>"+data.stuff[i].name+"</a></li>")
}
```

How to get the values in li elements?
I have tried different versions but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps. You need to attach `click event` to the `a` tag of the dropdown and display the selected text in a span having `selected` ID.

```
$('#dropDownId a').click(function () {
    $('#selected').text($(this).text());
});
```

```js
$(function () {
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     $("#dropDownId").append("<li><a data-value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</a></li>")
 }

 $('#dropDownId a').click(function () {
     $('#selected').text($(this).text());
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
 <div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" value="1" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle">
   <span id="selected">Select</span><span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropDownId">
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){

  $("#tmplDropDown").append("<li><a data-value='"+i+"'>test</a></li>")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" value="1" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle">
      Select  <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="tmplDropDown">
    </ul>
  </div>
```